# Asymptotic growth of recurrence sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

A sequence $(a_n)_{n≥0}$ in $R$ satisfies $6_ = a_{n-2} + a_{n-1},$ where $ _0 =-1$ $ _1 = -1$
Determine the asymptotic growth of $(a_n)_{n≥0}$.

My question is: Should we first solve this recurrence and then find the asymptotic growth?
I am familiar with the asymptotic growth functions and recurrences but I am not sure how to start this problem..

Any hint or idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurrence sequences have a lot in common with linear differential equations. Here we have the analogous differential equation
$$
6y'' - y' - y = 0,
$$
$y'(0) = -1$, $y(0) = -1$. Characteristic equation is $6\lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0$, $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}$. So the solution is $y = C_1 e^{\frac{1}{2}t} + C_2 e^{-\frac{1}{3}t}$. From the condition we obtain $C_1 = -\frac{8}{5}$ and $C_2 = \frac{3}{5}$. Now it's obvious that the asymptotic behaviour is close to $-\frac{8}{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}t}$ (or $-\frac{8}{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}n}$) since the second summand tends to zero.

Comment: This is such a great and understandable approach. Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @Arianita I'm glad to help. By the way, you can read more about this approach in Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations.

Answer (score 1):

This recurrence relation can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_{n-2} \\ a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence, by induction,
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Computing the eigendecomposition of $A := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\end{pmatrix}$ will give you the asymptotic growth of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Usually it will be determined by the largest eigenvalue of $A$ unless you exactly hit the eigenvector of the lower eigenvalue or the eigenvalues are equal in size.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your contribution